# Spring security logout link in Facelets

Tags: java, jsf, spring-security, jsf-2, facelets

I used to have JSPs implementing spring security logout like this:

```
<a id="logout" href="<spring:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" htmlEscape="true" />">Logout</a>
```

Later on when I changed to jsf 2, and started using Facelets, I can't get it to work anymore. I tried many ways. I tried this:

```
<a id="logout" href="&lt;spring:url value=&quot;/j_spring_security_logout&quot; htmlEscape=&quot;true&quot; &sol;&gt;">Logout</a>
```

But it wont work. Can someone please help me? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: also advise me please if i should use commandlink instead?

Comment: What kind of results you get from first and second trials after switching to JSF 2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout">logout</a>
```

or

```
<h:outputLink value="/j_spring_security_logout">logout</h:outputLink>
```

Comment: The above answer for outputlink will not work, as prepending the "/" takes to, server context root not the application context root, but our objective is to go to application's root, so #{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout, should be the right one.

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions:

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout">Logout1</a>
<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout">Logout2</h:outputLink>
```